# histograms using loop using R

Tags: r, loops, histogram

I am trying to find a more efficient way to plot these five histograms using a for loop for example how would I use a loop for the plots below in R

```
hist(dat$train[dat$train[,1]==7,10])
hist(dat$train[dat$train[,1]==7,2])
hist(dat$train[dat$train[,1]==7,17])
hist(dat$train[dat$train[,1]==7,200])
hist(dat$train[dat$train[,1]==7,56])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferably, for this kind of question, you should post some sample data for `dat`. In this case, only one variable changes within the loop. The `for` loop can loop over a vector of these values. Conventionally, the variable is calles `i`. I did not change your `hist`-statement except for inserting the `i`:

```
for(i in c(10, 2, 17, 200, 56))
    hist(dat$train[dat$train[,1]==7, i])
```

Personally, I prefer speaking variable names, so I would replace the `i` by `breaks`like so:

```
for(breaks in c(10, 2, 17, 200, 56))
    hist(dat$train[dat$train[,1]==7, breaks])
```

Comment: Here is a sample data for dat$train                                                                     V1 V2 V3 V4     V5     V6     V7     V8     V9    V10    V11    V12    V13    V14
4   7 -1 -1 -1 -1.000 -1.000 -0.273  0.684  0.960  0.450 -0.067 -0.679 -1.000 -1.000.....  but what you suggested works perfectly thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the anser. For the next time: Comments are not a good place for data, as comments are short and you can not use line feeds. Best practice is to ammend the question by editing it and putting the result of `dput(dat)` (or some sensible subset of `dat`, if `dat` is large`).